# Differences between asking questions on SO in general and in a specific Collective

Tags: support, questions, scope, collectives

Is there a difference from the point of view of *visibility* and *on-topic rules* between **asking questions** through "main" SO screen and using Collective-themed tag(s) and asking the same question in that Collective?

Comment: No, all that changes is it gets a pretty icon next to the tags and it shows up on an additional question list.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the visibility perspective, you're still asking the question on Stack Overflow, so it's visible to everyone that can see Stack Overflow questions.  That is to say, the only *real* difference is that the question would be labeled with the collective that you're a member of or have posted to, but that's about *it*.

From the topicality perspective, you're still asking the question on Stack Overflow, so it's subject to Stack Overflow's rules around topicality and fit for site.